# Automate Inventory adjustment - Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We are trying to automate the Inventory Adjustment whenever the Inventory OnHand hits 0 or less than 0. How can we implement this with in the Netsuite.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a user event on aftersubmit on the sales order record. Whenever the stock goes below on order, create the IA.

Comment: Could you please provide me to the steps to setup the User event for Inventory Adjustment